# How to stop auto play on carousel made with react-reveal/makeCarousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm planning on using a carousel made with `react-reveal/makeCarousel` as an ImageGallery.

So fas, I was not able to find a way to cancel the "auto-play" feature. I want the transtion to occur based on mouse clicks and touch only.

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.react-reveal.com/tutorials/carousel/

```
render (
  <Carousel defaultWait={1000} /*wait for 1000 milliseconds*/ >
    <Slide right>
      <div>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        <p>Slide Description</p>
      </div>
    </Slide>
    <Slide right>
      <div>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        <p>Slide Description</p>
      </div>
    </Slide>
  </Carousel>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that `defaultWait={0}` disables the auto-play.

```
render (
  <Carousel defaultWait={0} /* Disables autoplay */ >
    <Slide right>
      <div>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        <p>Slide Description</p>
      </div>
    </Slide>
    <Slide right>
      <div>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        <p>Slide Description</p>
      </div>
    </Slide>
  </Carousel>
);
```